# PDO - foreach only update the last one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm new to PDO and I'm having a problem with updating array values in a database. Everything works fine except for updating multiple values from an array.

HTML with PHP code:

```
<?php  
$next = 0;
echo '<ul>';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers LEFT JOIN products ON customers.product_code = products.product_code RIGHT JOIN transactions ON customers.transcode = transactions.transcode WHERE transactions.id = '$id'";

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo '<li>'.$row['product_name'] .' x <input name="p_qty['.$next++.']" type="number" value="'. $row['p_quantity'] .'"></li>';                    
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Output:

- MVP Incredible Bulk Gainer (8lbs) x 2
- MVP Incredible Bulk Gainer
  (16lbs) x 2
- Elite Labs 100% Isoblend (4 lbs) x 2

Whenever I try to change the quantity of the third results, both 1st and 2nd quantity also followed.

Here's the PDO code:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "UPDATE transactions JOIN customers ON transactions.transcode = customers.transcode SET transactions.transcode = ?, date = ?, customers.custname = ?, payment = ?, status = ?, customers.p_quantity = ? WHERE transactions.id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach($_POST['p_qty'] as $qty){
    $q->execute(array($transcode, $date, $custname, $payment, $status, $qty, $id));
}
Database::disconnect();
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: `ORDER BY somefield LIMIT 1`, or if you don;t know how to order `LIMIT 2, 1` and hope that `UPDATE` will process records in the same order as `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is pulling those 3 rows for the transaction ID in question.

Your update statement's where clause is also pulling only by the transaction ID, which means it will match those 3 rows.

If you'd like your update statement to change the quantity on just one of the products, you need to pass an additional field to the where clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm still new with this PDO thing.. 
How can i add additional field.. can u give a clue/an example? 

i'm using the same code as i'm updating single name, address, and whatsoever... but when it comes to array.. i can only update the last one. 

I've tried echo out $_POST['p_qty'],and it shows correctly in array order but only update the last one.

Comment: What is the schema of your product and transaction tables?